# Why I get package does not exist if i want to import an package with only an enum?

Tags: java, import, enums, package

I got `package xy does not exist`, but I have the package xy in this format:

```
package xy.Xy;

public enum Xy {
    some, things, in, an, usual, enum
}
```

And I want to import it in this way:

```
import xy.*;

public class Usual{
    //some usual things
}
```

The file system is like this:

```
_
 |- xy > Xy.java 
 |- usual > Usual.java
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Given you have `package xy.Xy;` for your `enum`, you **resolve** it with

```
import xy.Xy.*; // or, import xy.Xy.Xy because that is the fully qualified
                // class name.
```

If you want to use the `import` you say, then change the `package` declaration for the `enum Xy` to

```
package xy;
```

Comment: I tried with import xy.Xy.Xy but I got also package xy.Xy does not exist. I tried every combination what you wrote, but not worked for me.

Comment: You should also move `Xy.java` to a subfolder (`xy\Xy\Xy.java `) because the directory structure matches the package name. What compiler settings are you using? And do you really think a fully qualified class name of `xy.Xy.Xy` makes any sense whatsoever?

Comment: I am using only terminal with simple javac I tried also to move to a subfolder, but also the same error.